# How to navigate from Error dialog with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase with Flutter. 
After I retrieve documents as a contents list, I don't know how to handling screen. The code is in StreamBuilder.
I would like to show dialog at first, and after push dialog OK button, navigate the other next screen.

How ever following code does not navigate next screen.

```
final List<DocumentSnapshot> contents = snapshot.data.documents;

if (contents.length == 0) {
  try {
    print('NO DATA FOR THIS USER. ${contents.length}');
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text('Please Register First.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.push(context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  } catch (e) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

If I don't return Container, Error screen show up.

Comment: Try to print that `e` in the `catch` block and reply what it says..

Comment: Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2334 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.

Comment: @tajihiro Add `Navigator.pop(context)` before `Navigator.push`

Comment: *"If I don't return Container"* - return from where? the code you posted is part of `build()` method or what?

Comment: @Crazy Lazy Cat It does not work.

Comment: @pskink I return form catch block. Otherwise red error screen is behind dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me ,
You should remove the dialogue from the navigator stack and then do materialPageRoute.
So this would be the code.

And builder parameter of showDialog requires a parameter of type

> Widget Function(BuildContext)

hence , instead of underscore, try passing "context" as argument , as shown below.

```
final List<DocumentSnapshot> contents = snapshot.data.documents;

if (contents.length == 0) {
  try {
    print('NO DATA FOR THIS USER. ${contents.length}');
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text('Please Register First.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.pop(context);
                   Navigator.push(context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  } catch (e) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding Navigator.pop() before Navigator.push()?

Comment: Is this a function or inside build method. If inside function , try passing BuildContext build as argument and try. And as shown in answer , change the underscore ( "_") in builder parameter of ShowDialogue to context. This might solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I should have insert this code before the screen show up.
I had implemented this code wrong place. It is hard to explain.

However it worked.